# SharedPreferences wont save value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
final SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("birthday", 0);
final SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences("name", 0);

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString("birthday", birthday.getText().toString());
            editor.apply();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sp2.edit();
            editor2.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
            editor2.apply();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Changes saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The birthday value saves just fine but the name does not. why?

Comment: why are you using two different instances of SharedPreference ?

Comment: Can you confirm that the values you are trying to store actually exist and not null?

Comment: Agree with Blackbelt. You should be using one instance of SharedPreferences and one Editor.

Comment: Can you show how you are retrieving the stored values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString("birthday", birthday.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Changes saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Fixed the problem! Had to use only one instance of SharedPreferences instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString("birthday", birthday.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
editor.apply();
```

with

```
editor.commit();
```

Read more about it in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit())

Comment: I am sure apply() is recommended

Comment: apply is recommended. Apply works asynchronously. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: Because the answer you have given is a non-answer. Both methods will do the same task in different ways. apply is actually the recommended way in this case (doesn't seem like they care about a return value, and it is on the UI thread). Read the documentation.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer - if I did I would give a reason

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it when storing values in my app:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("birthday", birthday.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();  
     }
});
```

The issue I had when saving to preferences was how I actually obtained an instance of the SharedPreferences;

Would you please share the code that you use to instantiate sp?

I hope this helps!

Comment: SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("birthday", 0);
    SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences("name", 0);

Comment: Try this : PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);